# Computing the norm of an element of a segment joining two points

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $x,y\in X$ with $0<\left\|{x}\right\|<\left\|{y}\right\|$. Every element in the segment joining $x$ and $y$ has the form $z_t=ty+(1-t)x=x+t(y-x)$, with $t\in [0,1]$.

Since $\left\|{z_0}\right\|=\left\|{x}\right\|$ and $\left\|{z_1}\right\|=\left\|{y}\right\|$, I know that because of continuity, the image of $t\mapsto \left\|{z_t}\right\|$ contains (as pointed out by Isaac Browne) the interval $[\left\|{x}\right\|,\left\|{y}\right\|]$.

However, I'm interested in finding an explicit $t$ for every $r\in [\left\|{x}\right\|,\left\|{y}\right\|]$. In other words, for every $r\in [\left\|{x}\right\|,\left\|{y}\right\|]$ I would like to find $t$ such that $\left\|{z_t}\right\|=r$.

But I don't know how to solve the "equation" $$\left\|{x+t(y-x)}\right\|=r.$$

Any hint would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: One minor detail to be careful of. You know the image of $t\mapsto \left\|{z_t}\right\|$ contains the interval $[\left\|{x}\right\|,\left\|{z}\right\|]$, but it may be larger! If we take $X$ to be the real numbers with $x=-1$ and $y=1$, the image is actually $[0,1]$, not $[1,1]$

Comment: @IsaacBrowne I see, you're right! Thank you

Comment: Do you need a solution for arbitrary normed spaces? In an inner product space (such as $\Bbb R^n$) you can solve the quadratic equation $r^2 = \|x+t(y-x)\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + 2t\langle x, y-x \rangle + t^2 \| x-y\|^2$ for $t$.

Comment: @MartinR Actually that is helpful too, thanks!